# Shouldn't the word "confection" here be plural?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, nouns, uncountable-nouns, countability

Came across a sentence [here](http://www.esquire.com/entertainment/movies/a39472/james-bond-gadgets-supercut/):

> Unlike most blockbuster **confection**, the success of Bond depends on relevancy

If I am not mistaken, confection is a count noun. Shouldn't it be "unlike most blockbuster **confections**"?

On a different note, I also find the use of "relevancy" strange, where a simple "relevance" would do.

Comment: I am indeed aware of a previous discussion on "relevancy". https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230461/can-someone-explain-when-to-use-relevance-and-when-relevancy

Comment: *Confection* can be used as a noncount noun. A sort-of synonym you could substitute directly here is "cotton candy" (aka "candy floss", I think).

Comment: Your "relevancy" issue needs to be asked in a separate question.

Comment: Actually I provided a link to a discussion on ELU in a comment to show that the "relevancy" part is a comment, not a question.

Answer (score 1):

See [*confection*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/confection):

> 4. a product or work having a frivolous, whimsical, or contrived effect.

It would be non-count because it is a style or type of film rather than referring to specific films.

Comment: But according to Oxford, "1.1 An elaborately constructed thing, especially a frivolous one." It's still like a count noun if you look into those examples in this link: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/confection

Comment: Substitute a different categorization: "unlike most blockbuster junk food" or "unlike most blockbuster nonsense" or "unlike most blockbuster fluff". They are not referring to a specific list of movies but rather, as noted, a category or label.

Answer (score 1):

The OP is correct, this should be "confections". A "blockbuster confection" here is a specific film, a **member** of the category, not the category as a whole. Thus "confection" acts here as a countable noun, and should agree in number.

Note that the illustrative quote under sense 4 is

> the play was merely an ingenious confection

and the use of "an" indicates use as a countable (not count) noun.